# unable to add image to drawable folder in xamarin forms visual studio 2019

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image: Screenshot of Solution Explorer]

I am trying to add an image to drawable in `xamarin` forms app in visual studio 2019 I am getting an error as the system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: please specify the steps taken by you and also the screenshot you shared shows that images are in a folder named midmap-hdpi. I can't see any images in the folder you mentioned.

Comment: Right click on drawable Select Add Existing item Select Image Error is displayed as System can not find path specified

Comment: To try adding images just i have added it to mipmap folder

Comment: I am not able to see drawable folder in solution in file explorer too

Comment: try refreshing the resources folder in visual studio then right click on drawable folder and selected open in file explorer option this way you should be able to see the folder in file explorer if not then you might not have to permissions to read or edit the folder

Comment: ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: I am still getting above error

Comment: right click on the drawable folder and remove it from the solution and then try adding it if that does not work then the issue is that your folder was deleted using file Explorer and visual studio is not able to find it.

Comment: @Olivarsham glad to help :)

Answer (score 8):

Just had the same problem. Looks like the folder is there but in fact it isn't (Still a bug in visual studio for windows). Just delete the folder and add the folder yourself. Now you are able to add your image for your icon.

Comment: It works, so strange! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If not already exists. Create a folder `drawable`  in `XAML.Android\Resources` directory and try again. If already exists then delete it and recreate it. 
If all of above does not work then grant same permission to `drawable`  folder 
 which has `XAML.Android\Resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had the folder but adding the image file didn't work, what I had to do was to right-click of each folder and select **Add -> Existing Item**